# RemoteObjectManager не всегда обновляет метки на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Суть проблемы:
ROM обращается к серверу за данными при изменении текущей области (zoom, drag) и каждый раз получает необходимые данные, но не всегда их отрисовывает. Метки, полученные первым запросом, всегда показываются исправно, а потом начинаются пробои. Выглядит это следующим образом: открываешь страницу, все отлично отрисовано, отводишь карту на другую область, он ничего не рисует, приближаем зум на максимум, ничего нет, возвращаем назад, и вот только тогда появляются метки (каждое действие сопровождается запросом к серверу и успешным формированием данных). Что может быть?

object_manager.js:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init()
{
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', { center: [48.954206, 21.259468], zoom: 5 }, { controls: [] });

    var remoteObjectManager = new ymaps.RemoteObjectManager('/Home/GetTowns?coordsstr=%b',
    {
        // Опции кластеров задаются с префиксом cluster.
        clusterHasBalloon: false,
        // Опции объектов задаются с префиксом geoObject.
        geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: false
    });
    // Добавим менеджер на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(remoteObjectManager);
}
```

Возвращаемая с сервера строка json (100 объектов вместо 2):

```
id_155617265688350153594(
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":
[
{"type":"Feature","id":0,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[35.6894875000,139.6917064000]},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"Токио","balloonContentBody":"fff","balloonContentFooter":"fff","clusterCaption":"fff","hintContent":"Токио"}},
{"type":"Feature","id":99,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.6343021000,141.6053721000]},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"Томакомай","balloonContentBody":"fff","balloonContentFooter":"fff","clusterCaption":"fff","hintContent":"Томакомай"}}
]
})
```

Код страницы:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&amp;apikey=<apikey>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/object_manager.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:800px"></div>
```

Comment: Можно ли где-то увидеть это приложение работающим? В этом случае разобраться будет намного проще.

Comment: Проверьте, что значения id не совпадают у разных объектов на карте, от этого тоже часто бывают проблемы.

Comment: @se0ga, приложение только в разработке, id пока ставлю просто инкрементом. Может есть способ включить логирование на менеджере?

Comment: Не слышал про логирование.  "id пока ставлю просто инкрементом" если для каждого запроса вы ставите инкрементом, то это может означать, что одновременно на карте может существовать объекты с одинаковым id ? Если да, то такого быть не должно. Попробуйте сделать сквозную нумерацию для всех объектов, возможно это починит проблему.

Comment: @se0ga, да, все заработало. Теперь использую guid-идентификаторы из бд. Почему-то думал, что id должен быть уникальным в контексте одного запроса, а не всего времени жизни карты, так сказать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В Remote Object Manager объекты в ответе от сервера должны всегда иметь уникальное значение в поле id.

Если на карте в любой момент времени окажутся геообъекты любого типа с одинаковым значением в поле id, то это может привести к странным последствиям в виде пропадания части или всех геообъектов с карты.

Подробней о том как формировать ответ от сервера можно прочитать тут:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/361297)

Comment: Почему не является ответом на вопрос если мы уже в комментариях разобрались, что в этом и была проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более подробный ответ. Ваши комментарии под вопросом куда более подробны, чем сам ответ. Но, комментарии не все читают и они не являются дополнением к ответу.

Comment: Постарался улучшить его)